# Are 3 GB ram sticks real?

Tags: memory

I have a friend with the Samsung R780, has this configuration:

Memory: 6144MB 1066MHz DDR3
Memory Slot: 2 x SODIMM

That means 2x3GB?
That means a stick has one side is 2GB and another side is 1GB?

Won't this run in single channel with performance loss?

(no, the missing 2gb is not taken by the gpu, as it is Graphics Device: nVidia GeForce GT 330M with 1024MB GDDR3)

Comment: as real as $3 bills

Comment: what tool are you using to get the info? most decent tools give you pretty precise info on what you're using (WMIC, SIW etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's going to be a 4GB and a 2GB, not 2 x 3GB. You can generally (but not always) mix and match different size DIMMs or SODIMMs.

Comment: LOL i didn't think about that, as my friend was saying it was 3+3 to use the dual channel. This give me another question: why Samsung saved $20 on a $1600 laptop leading to performance loss due to the disabled dual channel?

Answer (score 0):

Some systems will accept larger DIMMs, such as 2 x 4GB, but only recognize part of the total capacity. The only way to know for sure is to look at the actual sticks.

I know this to be the case for 2007 iMacs, which "officially" support 4GB total RAM, but can be pushed to 6GB.